# How to fix table rows top

Tags: asp.net, css

I am going to replace the table with divs for that I used

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">Benefits</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">Preferences</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.div-table{ display:table; }
.div-table-row{ display:table-row;  }
.div-table-col{ display:table-cell; }
```

I want to fix the table rows top .div-table-row1, .div-table-row2, .div-table-row3 ... etc.

So that at runtime I could rearrange the rows by changing the styles of rows.
such that preferences could come in first row if I assign just .div-table-row1 to it.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want exactly, maybe some more context?

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to replace a perfectly valid table by something like this? And by rearrange, you mean, what? Like sorting on a certain column? In CSS?

Comment: @c4urself: Lets assume there is a table with rows. Suppose there are are three rows having different content such that row1 contains Content1, row2 contains Content2 and row3 contains Content3. What if I like to change the order of rows by changing the style of rows so row2 becomes row1, row3 could become row2 etc.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I have edited my question for further clarification

Comment: 1. You can't rearrange/sort rows with CSS. 2. Do you mean table-heading with table-row top? 3. Your CSS is essentially a way to mimic a `table` with block elements, the order of the `tr`s in your html won't change without Javascript.

Comment: @C4urself: that means it is only possible with javascript not with CSS.

Comment: Yes i need order of tr in html to change

Comment: Unless you give each individual row an absolute position. But then you'll have to know exactly how high they each are. And many browsers don't like absolutely positioned table cells.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it would be rather impractical to achieve that (assuming I got your objective right) using CSS. You'd need to move the `<div>`s by changing their positions e.g. using `position: absolute` -- again, this wouldn't make a lot of sense.

You might want to consider a JavaScript solution. Not suggesting jQuery in particular, but this jQuery plugin is pretty hand: [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

I'll recap the comments + answer.

1. The question was whether or not table-rows `tr` could be rearranged with CSS. They just take on the order in which they are coded in html.
2. The properties `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `display: table-row` essentially mimic an html `table` as their names suggest. See the [available display properties here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
3. You can achieve this with JavaScript of course. Take a look at [jQuery UI's Sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable) for example.

Comment: Don't you guys have any simple jquery instead of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you want to know clearly but in my case, i try [golovko fixedheader table](http://fixedheadertable.com) and it works fine even with dynamic table except some bugs .If the table is static,you can do with just css and js which control the height and width of table.